# Dynamically changing cell styles angular

Tags: angular

I have html table which is dynamically growing and i want to give a specific color to the background of a column based on its value dynamically what is the best way to do it without using extra variables to the array which shows data of the table?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should care to provide a minimum reproducible example of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ngStyle like below,

```
<td [ngStyle]="{'background-color':person.country === 'UK' ? 'green' : 'red' }"></<td>
```